# Selenium IDE: VerifyTextPresent alway returns true

Tags: search, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to search several hyperlinks in a page (dynamically generated in a table) whether they contain the value "hello".

I use:

```
<td>verifyTextPresent</td>
<td>hello</td>
<td></td>
```

and it always returns false

I use:

```
<td>verifyTextPresent</td>
<td></td>
<td>hello</td>
```

and it always returns true

What is the correct way to search for a string *anywhere* in a page?

Comment: Could you please share your code with us?

Comment: I have a complex page with many tables, boxes etc. 
I wan to be able to search *anywhere* in this page.
I assume I should be using the verifyTextPresent command, but this always returns TRUE or FALSE, according to the way I pass the parameters. 
Thank you

Comment: I understand but could you share the selenium code what you already wrote?

Comment: Aren't the two examples provided above enough? These are the two variations I used. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> verifyTextPresent(pattern) This command is deprecated. Use the
>   verifyText command with an element locator instead.

You should consider using VerifyText with a locator, which can be body:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>//body</td>
    <td>Search Term</td>
</tr>
```

But since you want it limited to links I suggest using this:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>//a[text()=&quot;Search Term&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Which will look for only links that contain your search text (exactly, but you can use the contains() function to partially match)

Comment: I can see that the answer is the use of verifyElementPresent command because verifyText checks only for pure text and not links.

Can you please elaborate on the example? I cannot set it to work.

Are the &quot; needed? Exactly like that?

Comment: make them unescaped quotes.